# installing X Windows in mac?

Tags: macos

I have been attempting to install and run [CalcHEP](https://theory.sinp.msu.ru/%7Epukhov/calchep.html) on Mac OS. However, after installation, I encounter an issue where running "[./calchep](https://theory.sinp.msu.ru/%7Epukhov/CALCHEP/calchep_man_3.3.6.pdf)" displays the message "X Windows not detected." This problem is likely caused by the absence of libX11 in the system. Could you please guide me on resolving this issue while utilizing minimal memory space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install Xquartz from https://www.xquartz.org/.

Comment: Do I need to install it before installing CalcHEP?

Comment: @poreys No. But you can easily try this yourself :-)

Comment: Thanks. It is working.